# Long to wide format with several duplicates. Circumvent with unique combo of columns

Tags: r, dataframe, multiple-columns

I have a dataset similar to this (real one is way bigger). It is in long format and I need to change it to wide format with one row per id. My problem is that there are a lot of different combinations of time, drug, unit and admin. Only a combination of time, drug, unit and admin will be unique and should only occur once pr id. I could not find a solution to this. I would like R to create unique combinations of columns so the data can be transformed to wide format.
 I have tried

`melt.data.table(df, id.vars=c(id,time,drug,unit,admin), measure.vars = c(dose), na.rm=F)`

and also a combination with

```
%>% expand(nesting(time, drug, unit, admin, dose), id)
```

but it doesn't work. Here is mock data:

```
id<-c(1492,1492,1492,1492,1493,1493)
time<-c("Pre-bypass","Post-bypass","Total","Post-bypass","Pre-OP","Pre-OP")
drug<-c("ACE","LEVO","LEVO","MIL","BB","BC")
unit<-c(NA,"ml/hr","ml","mg",NA,NA)
admin<-c(NA, "IV","IV","Inhale",NA,NA)
dose<-c(NA,50,40,5,NA,NA)
df<-rbind(id,time,drug,unit,admin,dose)
df<-t(df)
df<-as.data.table(df)
```

I would like my output to be something like this (the reason for the TRUE in Pre.bypass.Ace.unitNA.adminNA and Pre.OP columns is that dose and unit is missing here but because it is listed it is given in standard dose and unit:

```
id.new<-c(1492,1493)
Pre.OP.BB.unitNA.adminNA<-c(NA,TRUE)
Pre.OP.BC.unitNA.adminNA<-c(NA,TRUE)
Total.LEVO.ml.h.IV<-c(40,NA)
Pre.bypass.Ace.unitNA.adminNA<-c(TRUE,NA)
Post.bypass.LEVO.ml.h.IV<-c(50,NA)
Post.bypass.MIL.ml.h.IV<-c(5,NA)
df.new<-rbind(id.new,Post.bypass.MIL.ml.h.IV,Pre.OP.BB.unitNA.adminNA,Pre.OP.BC.unitNA.adminNA,Total.LEVO.ml.h.IV,Pre.bypass.Ace.unitNA.adminNA,Post.bypass.LEVO.ml.h.IV)
df.new<-t(df.new)
```

Comment: One row per id sounds like possibly the worst format for this data I could imagine. Is this strictly necessary?

Comment: The reason for this is I wanted to merge it with a large dataset that is already in wide format.

Comment: Why not make the other dataset long format? I deal with this sort of data everyday and analysing anything in wide format starts to border on impossible. Not to mention the huge waste in memory when 50+% of your cells are empty. And good luck trying to work with variables like `Post.bypass.MIL.ml.h.IV` and `Pre.bypass.Ace.unitNA.adminNA` - that's just a recipe for an undetectable coding mistake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with the comments that long format is usually the better way to go. If you have to use wide format the using the `tidyr` package you can do the following:

```
library(tidyr)
df %>% 
  unite(combination, time, drug, unit, admin) %>% 
  spread(key = combination, value  = dose)
```

Comment: This works. However, I can see your point about making the other data long format instead. I will consider that. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

```
library(data.table)
id <- c(1492, 1492, 1492, 1492, 1493, 1493)
time <- c("Pre-bypass", "Post-bypass", "Total", "Post-bypass", "Pre-OP", "Pre-OP")
drug <- c("ACE", "LEVO", "LEVO", "MIL", "BB", "BC")
unit <- c(NA, "ml/hr", "ml", "mg", NA, NA)
admin <- c(NA, "IV", "IV", "Inhale", NA, NA)
dose <- c(NA, 50, 40, 5, NA, NA)
df <- rbind(id, time, drug, unit, admin, dose)
df <- t(df)
df <- as.data.table(df)
df
#>      id        time drug  unit  admin dose
#> 1: 1492  Pre-bypass  ACE    NA     NA   NA
#> 2: 1492 Post-bypass LEVO ml/hr     IV   50
#> 3: 1492       Total LEVO    ml     IV   40
#> 4: 1492 Post-bypass  MIL    mg Inhale    5
#> 5: 1493      Pre-OP   BB    NA     NA   NA
#> 6: 1493      Pre-OP   BC    NA     NA   NA
```

Convert to wide with data.table package function dcast

```
data.table::dcast(df, id ~ ..., value.var = "dose")
#>      id Post-bypass_LEVO_ml/hr_IV Post-bypass_MIL_mg_Inhale
#> 1: 1492                        50                         5
#> 2: 1493                        NA                        NA
#>    Pre-OP_BB_NA_NA Pre-OP_BC_NA_NA Pre-bypass_ACE_NA_NA Total_LEVO_ml_IV
#> 1:              NA              NA                   NA               40
#> 2:              NA              NA                   NA               NA
```

Comment: This code works too. So I +1 both answers as they give the correct output. Will consider the long format comments though. Thanks.