# Long to Wide with Non-Unique Key Combinations in R

Tags: r

I am trying to convert a dataset from long to wide format. Need to do this to feed into another program for analysis purposes. My input data is below:

```
sdata <- data.frame(c(1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1),c(1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2),c("X1","A","B","C","D","X2","A","B","C","X1","A","B","C"),c(81,31,40,5,5,100,8,90,2,50,20,24,6))
col_headings <- c("Orig","Dest","Desc","Estimate")
names(sdata) <- col_headings
```

**Input Data**

[image: input data]

Depending on the unique combination of Orig-Dest-X1, Orig-Dest-X2 category above, the subcategories vary from only A,B,C to A,B,C,D to A,B, etc. I am trying to get the desired output (code to recreate in R below) along with image of desired output.

```
sdata_spread <- data.frame(c(1,1),c(1,2),c(81,50),c(31,20),c(40,24),c(5,6),c(5,NA),c(100,NA),c(8,NA),c(90,NA),c(2,NA))
col_headings <- c("Orig","Dest","X1",   "X1_A", "X1_B", "X1_C", "X1_D","X2",    "X2_A", "X2_B", "X2_C")
names(sdata_spread) <- col_headings
```

**Desired Output**

[image]

I tried the following:

```
sdata_spread <- sdata %>% spread(Desc,Estimate)
```

The error I got was:

```
Error: Each row of output must be identified by a unique combination of keys.
Keys are shared for 6 rows
```

I also tried the accepted answer given here: [Long to wide with no unique key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42560437/long-to-wide-with-no-unique-key) and here: [Long to wide format with several duplicates. Circumvent with unique combo of columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49909940/long-to-wide-format-with-several-duplicates-circumvent-with-unique-combo-of-col) but it did not get me the desired output.

Any insights would be much appreciated.

Thanks,
Krishnan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is to create a grouping variable based on the occurrence of 'X' as the first character in the 'Desc', use that to modify the 'Desc' by `paste`ing the `first` element of 'Desc' with each of the element based on a condition in `case_when` and reshape to wide format with `pivot_wider` (from `tidyr_1.0.0`, `spread/gather` are getting deprecated and in its place `pivot_wider/pivot_longer` are used)

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(stringr)
sdata %>%
  group_by(grp = cumsum(str_detect(Desc, '^X'))) %>% 
  mutate(Desc = case_when(row_number() > 1 ~ str_c(first(Desc), Desc, sep="_"),
            TRUE ~ as.character(Desc))) %>%
  ungroup %>% 
  select(-grp) %>% 
  pivot_wider(names_from = Desc, values_from = Estimate)
# A tibble: 2 x 11
#   Orig  Dest    X1  X1_A  X1_B  X1_C  X1_D    X2  X2_A  X2_B  X2_C
#  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#1     1     1    81    31    40     5     5   100     8    90     2
#2     1     2    50    20    24     6    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA
```

Comment: I found that for the last line of code above provided by akrun, doing 
spread(Desc,Estimate) instead of pivot_wider also works.

Comment: @Krishnan. `spread/gather` are getting deprecated in favor of `pivot_wider/pivot_longer`